# how to concatenate files according check box selection using system call in php

Tags: php, system-calls

I have some files in php ,i need to concatenate on basis of selection of checkboxes.if one checkbox is selected concatenate according to requirement and so on.this i have to do using system call ,and i'm working in php and ssh (secure shell client)

Comment: it would b grt if u paste ur triedout code here, I understood what u need, but i prefer u too provide some work u have already done on this to get theoutput...

Comment: what do you need to concatenate? the php files? what is selected by the checkboxes? what checkboxes? what is "according to requirement"? why system call? you need to be much more precise and detailed for us to be able to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you get files into an array, with HTML like

```
<?php
$files = array('file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt'); 
?>
<form action="action.php" method="post">
   <?php foreach ($files as $k => $files) { ?>
      <input type="checkbox" name="files[<?php echo $k;?>]" value="<?=$k;?>" />
   <?php } ?>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="ok" />
</form>
```

You can access checked checkboxed with php

```
<?php
    //I've made assumption outfile is in same path as source files
    $path = '/var/www/whatever/to/files/';
    $dest_file = $path . 'out.txt';
    //create empty file if not exists
    passshtru("touch $dest_file;");
    foreach ($_POST['files'] as $key) {
      $source_file = $path . $files[$key];
      //co contactenation using shell redirect
      passthru("cat $source_file >> $dest_file;");
    }

    //do whatever you want with generated file in /var/www/whatever/to/files/out.txt
```

You could need to put real path to binaries `touch` and `cat`, depending on your system config. 
I'm curious to know where is the need to do this with system calls, is theses files big ?